# Do I need to add recover for Future if the enclosing logic will not throw an exception

Tags: scala

In the following code, I am doing some processing. As far as I can understand, the logic which could throw an exception is within try/catch and I convert the error from exception into value

```
def finishResetCredentials(token:String):Future[Tuple3[Option[Throwable],String,Option[UserToken]]] = Future {
//get some values
    val hostOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.host")
    val redirectUrlOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.finishResetCredentialsRedirectUrl")
    val successfulOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.successfulResetCredentialsUrlParameter")
    val failedOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.failedResetCredentialsUrlParameter")

    val host = hostOption.getOrElse("")
    val redirectUrl = redirectUrlOption.getOrElse("")
    val successUrlParameter = successfulOption.getOrElse("")
    val failUrlParameter = failedOption.getOrElse("")
    val errorRediectedUrl = s"http://${host}${redirectUrl};${failUrlParameter}"
    val successRedirectedUrl = s"http://${host}${redirectUrl};${successUrlParameter}"

    //The databases will be queried only if the url and parts were read successfully
    if (host == "" || redirectUrl == "" || successUrlParameter == "" || failUrlParameter == "") {
      (Some(MissingConfigurationException()),errorRediectedUrl,None)
    } else {
      val userTokenKey = UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token))
      try{
        val generatedToken = userTransactionDatabaseService.finishResetCredentials(userTokenKey)
        (None,successRedirectedUrl,Some(generatedToken))
      } catch {
        case exception => (Some(exception),errorRediectedUrl,None)
      }

    }
  }
```

Could the above logic ever throw an error which doesn't get caught and could propagate to calling function? Eg. do I need to add recover in the following logic?

```
def finishResetCredentialsScalar(token:String) = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {
    implicit request => {
      for((exception,redirectUrl,generatedToken) <- userTransactionService.finishResetCredentials(token) ) yield {
        if(exception.isDefined){
          Redirect(redirectUrl)
        } else {
          Redirect(redirectUrl).withCookies(Cookie("reset-password-token", s"${generatedToken.get.tokenId}")).withCookies(Cookie("user", s"${generatedToken.get.userKeys.email}")) 
        }

      }
      /*res.recover {... }*/ //do I need this?
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the following code is might be exception throwing because I don't know what it does.

```
val hostOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.host")
val redirectUrlOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.finishResetCredentialsRedirectUrl")
val successfulOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.successfulResetCredentialsUrlParameter")
val failedOption = config.getOptional[String]("mail.failedResetCredentialsUrlParameter")

MissingConfigurationException()

UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token))
```

If that cannot throw an exception, then you don't need the recovery code for the future.

But this might be better to think forward. Somewhen you will change the code, and you might miss a possibility of an exception.

I think that it is a better design when you write your code that wouldn't fail in the upcoming future. And it is better if you transform EVERY exception to your custom error encoding - `(Some(exception),errorRediectedUrl,None)`.

Actually, in your case, you don't need the try/catch block at all - you can generalize any exception processing, just with recovering with `(Some(exception),errorRediectedUrl,None)`. You don't need to do it inside `finishResetCredentials` because there are no scoped variables that you add to your error tuple. You easily can get `errorRediectedUrl` from the global/static scope.